# TypeError in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I tried the Tensorflow model that defines k and x in the  equation of straight line. 
But I collided with incomprehensible to me problem. I'm new at this so I can't explain you my problem without tons of code, sorry. Below I'll leave my code. Help me please. Thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfc
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    with tf.name_scope("placeholders"):
        x = tfc.placeholder(tf.float32, (3, 1))
        y = tfc.placeholder(tf.float32, (3, ))
    with tf.name_scope("weights"):
        W = tf.Variable(tfc.random_normal((1, 1)))
        b = tf.Variable(tfc.random_normal((1,)))
    with tf.name_scope("prediction"):
        y_pred = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        l = tf.reduce_sum((y-y_pred)**2)
    #Добавить оптимизацию тренировки
    with tf.name_scope("optim"):
        #Задать скорость заучивания .001, как рекомендовано выше.
        train_op = tfc.train.AdamOptimizer(.001).minimize(l)
    with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
        #Запись сводки о переменных(скалярных величинах) в заданный каталог журналов
        tf.summary.scalar("loss", l)
        #Объединение нескольких сводок в одну
        merged = tfc.summary.merge_all()

    train_writer = tfc.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/lr-train', graph)

    n_steps = 1000

    with tfc.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tfc.global_variables_initializer())
        #Натренировать модель
        for i in range(n_steps):
            feed_dict = {x: [[1.], [2.], [3.]], y: [2., 3., 4.]}
            _, summary, loss = sess.run([train_op, merged, l], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
```

In the end I get this answer

```
    File "/Users/ss/Desktop/mac/TensorFlow/Z1.py", line 34, in <module>
    _, summary, loss = sess.run([train_op, merged, l], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1165, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 474, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 266, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 375, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 375, in <listcomp>
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 263, in for_fetch
    (fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: I just tried running your code, and everything is fine. I am not getting the error message you are getting. Are you not posting all of your code?

Comment: No, it's all of code

Comment: what I can do ?